# How to add Depth of field in Cycles render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I find myseld wanting to add multiple visual effects in Blender Cycles but I can't find any, like Bloom and depth of field etc.
How do I go about adding these in my cycles renders?

Comment: You can enable the DOF in the camera's properties tab.

Comment: bloom is a post effect that can be done in compositing.

Comment: Yes there's no simple bloom option in Cycles, you need to go through the Compositing. And as Ffeller says, if you select your camera and go in the Properties panel > Object Data tab, there's a Depth Of Field option that you can enable and set.